# Setting file upload path from request.querystring

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I ma trying to set an upload path using a fixed URL with an additional folder being read from the URL

```
Dim uploadsDirVar
uploadsDirVar = "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\psonline_v1\technical-requests\uploads\"+request.querystring("folder")
```

This doesn't seem to pick up the `folder` element of the `request.querystring("folder")`, I think I am missing something really simple, so if anyone could point it out to me that would be great.

Comment: Could you copy and past the url of request.querystring?

Comment: This is the URL I am using, http://192.168.1.12/technical-requests/testing/uploadTester.asp?folder=4

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `action` of the `form` to `action="uploadTester.asp?folder=<%=Request.QueryString("folder")%>"` and the upload now seems to be working fine.